# get error when try to generation rsakey.key

Tags: macos, terminal, rsa, applepay

I'm trying to connect Apple Pay with one of the payment systems. I need to make various certificates, verify them, etc. I do everything according to the guide, but at the moment of the command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out Certificates.p12 -inkey rsakey.key -in merchant_id.pem
```

i get an error in terminal:

[image]

Comment: Does `rsakey.key` actually exist in the current working directory with that exact name?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm not sure. if it is not there, then it should be generated?

Answer (score 0):

everything is very simple. it was necessary to move rsakey.key to the certificate folder